# ApplicationUser always null ASP.NET CORE 3.0 Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

When I try to get my users från the table AspNetUsers the users always return null even though there is a user in the table.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public string ProfileImageUrl { get; set; }
    public DateTime MemberSince { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to show is Posts with Author information

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public virtual Foorum Forum { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<PostReply> PostReplies { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how I'm getting Posts and Users and User is always null here.

```
 public Foorum GetById(int id)
    {
        var forum = _forumDbContext.Forums.Where(f => f.Id == id)
            .Include(f => f.Posts)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.User)
            .Include(f => f.Posts)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.PostReplies)
            .ThenInclude(r => r.User)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        return forum;
    }
```

This is how my DbContext looks like:

```
    public class ForumDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public ForumDbContext(DbContextOptions<ForumDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Foorum> Forums { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PostReply> PostReplies { get; set; }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ForumDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ForumDbContext>();
}
```

And I've also added app.UseAuthentication(); app.UseAuthorization(); in the Configure method.

What am I missing here, why can't I get users from the database?

Comment: *this is how I'm getting Posts and Users and User is always null here*:   Could you please check the database and make sure  the forum with that Id has a post which has an user **associated with** that post?

Comment: How do you map the relationship between posts and users?

Comment: I am having the similar problem.   One thing I see wrong with your code is that you have the line  services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options ...

This should be 

services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options ...

I am not posting this as a solution because I don't have one yet

Comment: Voting to close as "needs details or clarity" because the clarification asked in comments above is essential.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE**

**Change `IdentityUser` to `ApplicationUser` in `Startup.cs` & `ForumDbContext.cs` files, it may help.**

---

As I mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59693088/4040066), you should add a property `UserId` and just set it to the desired `User Id` such as `_currentUser.Id`. The entity framework will include `User` into your model automatically.

Comment: Wrong. `UserId` is not a *navigation property* and EF core will never include `User` *automatically*. Also, answering is useless until OP answers some questions asked to them in comments.

Comment: @GertArnold, the question is clear and the problem is in the `Post` model. He should add `UserId` property to `Post` class, and set it while creating a new post.

Comment: Clear how? It doesn't even show how posts are saved, so there's no certainty whatsoever if the database records have proper foreign key values. But clear or not, your answer is wrong nonetheless.

Comment: He has used `ApplicationUser` type in `Post` class. but in the `Startup.cs` he has used `IdentityUser`.

Comment: See? Nothing but ambiguity and obscurity.

Comment: Look at this solution. It may help you.  Seems you can not inject ApplicationUser but you can derive it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59707707/core-3-0-applicationuser-is-always-empty